# Play 2 songs on the same computer (Jack and HDMI)

Tags: audio, debian, hdmi

I'm thinking about the idea which could solve a lot of my problems.

I've a barebone computer and I would like to use HDMI port to play the first music and and the jack for the second.

I've seen some adaptors HDMI -> VGA/Jack

That's why I'm thinking about this idea to play my 2 musics in the same time on 2 different output.

I'm using `Debian 7` and I can do/install whatever you want to solve this problem.

Does anyone know if it's possible to do that or just pur madness?

Comment: HDMI won't allow you to output anything until compatible display device (like TV) is connected. I would suggest to buy USB audio adapter ($10-$30 based on audio quality required) to have 2 independent audio outputs.

Comment: Ok. And how is this customizable? How can I managed those 2 audio outputs? (see my comment on the answer of @shivams)

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely possible. I had done it previously on my Ubuntu. What you will need to install is `qjackctl` which is a user interface for controlling JACK (Jack Audio Connection Kit).

You will have to look at a few tutorials on how to set up and properly use JACK and then you can use `qjackctl` to configure which application's output goes to which audio port on your computer. The configuration screen of `qjackctl` is pretty intuitive. A screenshot as an example:

[image]

Comment: I've seen this soft but don't install or try it yet. My problem is a bit deeper. What about 2 different Google Chrome instances each on different output. Do you think it's possible? (I'm running chrome form command line. This means I can specify something if necessary to make the difference between those 2 instances)

Comment: Yes. Definitely. Two different chrome instances mean 2 different processes and hence very much possible.

Comment: Great! And how can I make the link between my chrome start (command line) and JACK? I need to have an automatic process to match both instances and audio outputs.

Comment: By the way, I can only see 1 output client (I can't see any HDMI device)